# Hiding PHP URL Parameters that come from the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, xss, url-parameters

so I'm a noob to PHP and I am trying to secure my url parameters that use PHP to gain unique pages, and currently they are open to cross site scripting and wondered how I could fix this?

```
 <?php  if ($result = $link->query("SELECT league_name, role, start_date, 
 end_date, joincode, active
            FROM leagues
            WHERE unique_id='$unique_id'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))


            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
              <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td scope="row" data-label="League Name"><a class="action" href="leagueinfo.php?league_name=<?php echo $row['league_name']; ?>&joincode=<?php echo $row['joincode']; ?>"><?php echo $row['league_name'] ?></a></td>

             </tr>
            <?php }  $result->close(); ?>
          </tbody>
              </table>

              <?php mysqli_close($link); ?>
```

So I need to find a way to make sure this doesn't happen:

[image: Script has been entered into url]

Comment: Use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Note, your edit doesn't show an example of SQL injection, it shows an example of cross-site scripting.

Comment: Ah, got them mixed up, working on both haha

Comment: Note, you *also* have SQL injection issues in this code. :)

Comment: `urlencode($row['league_name'])`

Comment: Would be also nice to see /leagueinfo.php as that seems to be the source of most of your XSS issues (PHP code which accepts the GET parameters `league_name` and `joincode`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO, prepared statements provide a good way of protection against SQL injection:
 1. Prepare your query with empty values as placeholders. 
 2. Bind values to the placeholders.
 3. Execute your query.

```
//PDO
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT league_name, role, start_date, end_date, joincode, active FROM leagues WHERE unique_id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different values that need to be encoded:

- `$unique_id` should be escaped for MySQL, or the query should be parameterized instead. (See [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).)
- `league_name` and `joincode` inside the url should be url encoded, which also happens to remove html special characters. (See [rawurlencode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php))
- `league_name` in the anchor text should be html encoded (see [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars)).